# Arithmetic in arguments to the geometry package

Tags: margins, paper-size, calculations, geometry

I'd like to use the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package to auto-crop the output of my LaTeX (so that it looks bigger on-screen as I'm editing). I have found a way to remove the margins completely and brutally:

```
\geometry{paperwidth=\textwidth,  paperheight = \textheight, margin=0cm}
```

However, I'd like to be somewhat more gentle. I tried the following, but it does not work:

```
\geometry{paperwidth=\textwidth + 1cm,  paperheight = \textheight+1cm, margin=1cm}
```

The reason is that arithmetic does not work inside these arguments. (LaTeX doesn't seem smart enough to do the addition).

What is the correct way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It works if you load the [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{paperwidth=\textwidth+1cm,paperheight=\textheight+1cm, margin=1cm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

`\dimexpr` allows for expression-like addition/subtraction of dimensions:

```
\usepackage{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\geometry{
  paperwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth + 1cm\relax,
  paperheight=\dimexpr\textheight+1cm\relax, 
  margin=1cm}
```

[`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) automates this process through a redefinition of the length/dimension-related macro (`\setlength`, `\addtolength`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you! Apparently, I need another two reputation points to vote up, but I'm sure others will do it for me.

Comment: @user21952-is-a-great-name You should be able to upvote soon enough. :-)

Comment: Just for information for those who do know it that division by floating point number is not allowed in , for example, `\dimexpr\textwidth/3.14\relax`.

Comment: @HiggsBoson: Perhaps, but multiplication is fine: `0.3183\textwidth` where `0.3183` ~ 1/π.

Comment: @Werner: Yes. I agree. But fp is more expressive. :-)

Answer (score 6):

`\dimexpr...\relax` is not flexible enough because you cannot do division by a floating point number. `\dimexpr\textwidth/3.141592654\relax`, for example, is not possible!

That is why I prefer using the [`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) package because it can do any calculation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval{Width}{round(pow(0.5,2)*10*sin(pi/2):3)}% $10\sqrt(2)$ in 3 digits
%     after decimal point
\FPeval{Height}{round(pow(0.5,3)*10+cos(pi/2):3)}% $10\sqrt(3)$ in 3 digits
%    after decimal point

\usepackage
[
    paperwidth=\Width cm,
    paperheight=\Height cm,
]
{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```